# Get Session Value in Joomla

Tags: session

I am using some simple JavaScript and php to get the session info to my console like so:-

```
var id='<?php $s=&JFactory::getSession();echo $s->getName();?>';
console.log(id);
```

The problem is this just logs out the session Name and not the Value which I would like to get. I have opened my website in both Chrome and Safari in Incognito mode and I seem to get the same Name every time, but the Value always differs for each session I create, so this is ideally what I want, as shown below:-
[image]
Currently I am getting '702d8d624abba227e9a0ac028c287b2a' logged, which is the Name, how do I get the Value of this? I have tried just about every related topic on SE and found nothing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var id='<?php $s = JFactory::getSession(); echo $s->getId();?>';
console.log(id);
```

Simple. That's enough internet for today.

For more information on accessing session information please see the [Joomla Session API Documentation](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JSession.html#method_getId)